# Wrap function and still have the same type information for input and output

Tags: typescript, function

Below I have `getEntityId` and I'd like to create a wrap function that can be use across many functions `getOrFail` that takes a function and returns a function that calls the passed in function, and asserts that it is true before returning or throwing.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash'

export const getEntityId = (value: any, entity: string): number | null => {
  if (typeof value === 'number') return value
  if (_.get(value, 'id')) return value.id
  if (_.get(value, `${entity}Id`)) return value.id
  return null
}

export const getOrFail = <A, T> (fn: (...a: T[]) => A, message) => (...args: T[]) => {
  const value = fn(...args)
  if (value) return value
  throw new Error(message);
}

export const getEntityIdOrFail = getOrFail(getEntityId, 'failed getting entity id')
```

I also tried this:

```
export const getOrFail = (fn, message) => (...args: ArgumentTypes<typeof fn>): ReturnType<typeof fn> => {
  const value = fn(...args)
  if (value) return value
  throw new Error(message);
}
```

I am looking for a way using generics to make it so that `getEntityIdOrFail` has the correct type information. How is this possible?

So I need to understand three thing:

1. How to pass along `fn` type parameters's to `(...args)`
2. How to pass along `fn` return type
3. How to remove `null` from the return value

Answer (score 0):

You could overload the function with versions with different numbers of parameters:

```
function getOrFail<A1, R>(fn: (a1: A1) => R, message: string): (a1: A1) => Exclude<R, null>;
function getOrFail<A1, A2, R>(fn: (a1: A1, a2: A2) => R, message: string): (a1: A1, a2: A2) => Exclude<R, null>;
function getOrFail<A1, A2, A3, R>(fn: (a1: A1, a2: A2, a3: A3) => R, message: string): (a1: A1, a2: A2, a3: A3) => Exclude<R, null>;
function getOrFail(fn: any, message: string) {
    return ((...args: any[]) => {
  const value = fn(...args)
  if (value) return value
  throw new Error(message);
});
}

// getEntityIdOrFail is of type (a1: any, a2: string) => number
export const getEntityIdOrFail = getOrFail(getEntityId, 'failed getting entity id')
```